# Dropzone.js with angular. Cannot get thumbnail to disappear upon image delete

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dropzone.js

Here is my code:

`Dropzone.options.dropZoneMedia = {
            maxFileSize: 10,
            maxFiles: 1,
            dictDefaultMessage: "Drop file here or click to upload",
            dictMaxFilesExceeded: "You may only upload one file",
            init: function(){
                this.options.addRemoveLinks = true;
                this.options.dictRemoveFile = "Delete";
            },
            success: function(file, response){
                $scope.imageId = response.id;
                $scope.addedImage.push($scope.imageId);
            },
            removedfile: function(id){
                MediaService.deleteFile($scope.imageId)
                    .then((response) => {
                        $scope.deletedResponse = response;
                        console.log($scope.deletedResponse);
                    })
            },
        }`

The removed file function takes in the ID, calls the service, I get the success response that image has been deleted from the server, but I cannot figure out how to remove the thumbnail from the dropzone after it's been deleted. Thoughts?

Comment: problem solved. I re-wrote it like this.
``` this.on("removedfile", function($index){
                    $scope.addedImages.splice($index, 1);
                    MediaService.deleteFile($scope.imageId)
                        .then((response) => {
                            $scope.deletedResponse = response;
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                }) ```